# List view - auto modify height

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Android and now I have this tutorial: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1928230

I modify (I want scroll all page) this and i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/petList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="700dp" //here!!!!
            android:divider="#000"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonAddNews"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add new Pet" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Single item:

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="two" ></TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:text="three" 
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This working ok, but i must modify android:layout_height.

For example if i have 3 item in list then 700dp it is too more. 
If I use fill_parent, match_parent or wrap_content then this show me only one item (I can scroll it).

What I have to type in the layout_height to automatically expanding, with the number of items?

Comment: make  android:layout_height="fill_parent" for both ScrollView and LinearLayout

Comment: Still does not work. Could you give an example? Maybe I'm wrong fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: REMOVE THAT SCROLLVIEW!! Never place a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`! Google for "android listview inside scrollview" to get more information about that.

Now, usually you would implement that layout somehow like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/petList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp" // set layout_height=0dp
        android:layout_weight="1" // add layout_weight=1
        android:divider="#000"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonAddNews"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add new Pet" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

This way the list will use the whole available height, except what the button is using. If you want the button to scroll with the list, use a list footer.

Comment: Ok, height now working, but scrolling doesnt working. If i have for example 15 items, then items after number 10 are below the screen. I want scrolling all page - with button.

Comment: The `ListView` is a `ScrollView`, so it should scroll by itself. If you want the button to be part of the list and scroll with it, than add it as a list footer. You'll figure out how with the help of google.